# Brew doctor says: "Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable."

Tags: macos, homebrew

Brew doctor says:

> Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable. This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by Homebrew.
>
> If a brew tries to write a header file to this directory, the install
>   will fail during the link step.
>
> You should probably `chown` /usr/local/include

I've tried different commands to solve this but I'm still stuck here.

I'm running homebrew on 10.8.2

Comment: I got a similar error for "/usr/local/lib" in Homebrew 0.9.4 that was also resolved with the solution below.

Answer (score 812, accepted):

Take ownership of it and everything in it.

Mac OS High Sierra or newer: (ty to Kirk in the comments below)

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Previous versions of macos:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/include
```

Then do another

```
$ brew doctor
```

Comment: operation not permitted?

Comment: Any advantage instead of `$ sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local/`?

Comment: @WillemLabu one less process fork? whoami is effective user id and as the man page says is obsolete :)  bash is default shell on OSX and somewhere USER is getting set.

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you. I checked `man whoami` and that suggests `\`\`id -p\`\`` - that echoes uid and groups though. Your suggested `$USER` echoes just my username. Neat.

Comment: I wonder whether changing ownership of /usr/local to a user a clean solution.  Wouldn't it be better to add $USER to the 'wheel' group?  Or change the group of /usr/local to the admin group?

Comment: @MichaelLehn This is directly from homebrew documentation and homebrew depends on it. Given that most mac's are effectively single user computers and not shared systems, it does not matter, IMO.  A group and maintaining g+w would be a bigger challenge given umask defaults to 022. Keeping umask of 002 in /usr/local and 022 elsewhere would be difficult.

Comment: Does this properly undo the effect of `sudo make install`, or is this a "dirty" way?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes, and this is by design and documented in homebrew. If you use homebrew you must (unless you want to deal with these warnings) commit all of /usr/local to homebrew. So you would never run sudo make install, homebrew would do that for you.

Comment: @jrwren By "undo" I mean "undo with respect to system defaults." `chown` feels like a hack to me. Since I'm an admin user, I did `chmod g=u`; is there a reason `chown` is better?

Comment: @ssdecontrol /usr/local is an empty folder or nonexistent by default, as for its ownership, I cannot tell you. Certainly this has no relation to a "sudo make install". But in short: Yes, this deviates from a default OSX install.

Comment: @jrwren actually, I had no problems with Homebrew until I ran `sudo make install`, and, as you can see, `brew doctor` itself suggests that running `sudo make install` can cause this exact ownership problem. My guess is that library developers use hard-coded ownership/permission - modifying commands in their makefiles, but I also have no idea how makefiles work.

Comment: @ssdecontrol it sounds like you have an entirely different issue. What software are you installing? Are you using homebrew to do it? If no, then use a different PREFIX than /usr/local. Also, because you already own /usr/local, there is no reason to use sudo. You can run make install.

Comment: I was installing GSL manually to debug something, but that doesn't matter. I didn't realize `/usr/local` was created by Homebrew, so I guess the answer is "do what you want." Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Taking ownership like this doesn't help for me. I still get the error that files are not writable... Any suggestion?

Comment: @NicolasV: Make sure you own /usr/local.

Comment: Doesn't work, throws `illegal user name` error on OS X 10.11.4. `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /usr/local/` worked like a charm though.

Comment: How long does this command take to run? It's been going for about 5 minutes on my laptop and I have no way of knowing the status or progress.

Comment: According to [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228) in Mac OS High Sierra chown `/usr/local` doesn't work anymore. Instead use `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

Comment: $ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/* did the trick in mojavae 10.14

Comment: I got updated from Sierra to Mojave, and I needed to reinstall all brew to fix this error 
Now everything is working as intended

Answer (score 123):

What worked for me was too

```
sudo chmod g+w /usr/local
sudo chgrp staff /usr/local
```

Comment: This is the only sane fix, not really sane to take ownership of /usr/local in a multiuser os

Comment: Well, not in High Sierra. "Unable to change file mode on /usr/local: Operation not permitted"

Comment: @user980018 I just ran into the same thing - here's the [workaround I used](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-1)

Answer (score 40):

What worked for me was

```
$ sudo chown -R yourname:admin /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 40):

The only one that worked for me on El Capitan was:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

Comment: chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Comment: @AlxVallejo doing it on /usr/local/bin worked for me

Comment: For anyone reading now: if sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local results in an error on Big Sur, try sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include

Comment: Why would you want to do this? These files are meant to be owned by root and the admin group, not your local user..

Answer (score 27):

If you are on **High Sierra** and experiencing this issue, follow the steps below (**Note: /usr/local cannot be chown'd in High Sierra**):

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/include
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Then try linking with brew link. I was experiencing similar issue and none of the solutions above worked for High Sierra. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I tried a lot. Brew doctor told that the dir is missing. Your answer helped me and am able to do the work. Thank you.
Mac Users, Please try this.

Answer (score 24):

For High Sierra:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then, try your brew commands.

[Issue #3285](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3285)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, if you previously had brew installed and upgraded to High Sierra, reinstalling Homebrew fixes the issue. This is the easiest approach

Comment: Ironically that's because the script does exactly what the other answers are suggesting.

Comment: This worked for me but first i uninstalled the previous using: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

Answer (score 12):

You can alias the command to fix this problem in your `.bash_profile` and run it every time you encounter it:

At the end of the file `~/.bash_profile`, add:

```
alias fix_brew='sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/'
```

And now inside your terminal you can run:

```
$ fix_brew
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me on **macOS 10.12**

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`

I had the problem updating homebrew with the following error:

```
/usr/local is not writable. You should change the ownership
and permissions of /usr/local back to your user account:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

Answer (score 10):

First you need to create the directory:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/include
```

Second:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Answer (score 8):

For some it's going to be:

```
sudo chown -R JonJames:admin /usr/local/lib
```

where "lib" is used as opposed to "bin" or "include" or "whatever else"

The Homebrew **Warning** "should" explain what specifically is not writable and then give you a command syntax for follow, however you will need to use the ":" as opposed to what the Warning mentions which is actually not correct syntax??

Comment: The syntax in the Warning is a bit confusing I believe, I emailed the lead contributor for Homebrew to ask if they would change anything about it, awaiting reply, perhaps the Warning's verbiage will change in future brew updates..

Comment: thanks! This worked after a fair amount of searching around.

Answer (score 7):

Work for me

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local

$ cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
```

Answer (score 5):

Same error on MacOS 10.13

`/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/` `/usr/lib` were not created. I manually created and `brew link` finally worked.

Answer (score 4):

What Worked for me, while having I have **more** than 1 user on my computer.

Using terminal:

- Running `brew doctor`

  - Seeing multiple `/usr/local/...` isn't writable error's
- Disabling Mac's System Integrity Protection: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/55628
- Run the following
- `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*`
- `brew doctor && brew upgrade && brew doctor`

> Running Macbook Pro OSX High Sierra (version 10.13.3.)

EDIT 1:

> FYI - Please be Advised this causes an issue with running MySQL on your MAC.
>
> To be able to start my local server, I had to run:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

After you run this you can start your local MySQL Server.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib if they don't exists:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include
$ sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/include
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/sbin

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/sbin
```

This will create all required directories and give it the correct ownership.

After running these commands check with: `brew doctor`

This works for Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get control of entire `/usr/local` to do that you need to do a recursive `chown` under `/usr/local`

`sudo chown -R YOUR_USERNAME:admin /usr/local/`

Answer (score 2):

I just want to echo [sam9046](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010020/sam9046)'s modest comment as an alternative and potentially much easier solution that worked in my case: [uninstall](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew) and [install](https://brew.sh/) homebrew again from scratch.  No sudo commands required.

You can also browse/modify the uninstall script from that link above if you need to ensure it won't affect your previously installed packages.  In my case this was just my home machine so I just started over.

Comment: See https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3665#issuecomment-357175220

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen in my organization after all our users were bound to active directory (effectively changing the UID from 50x to ######).

Now it is simply a case of changing the ownership of all files where were owned by x to y.

Where 501 is my old numeric user id which is still associated with all the homebrew files.

The old user id can be found using `ll /usr/local/Cellar`

Now update the ownership
`sudo find /usr/local -user 501 -exec chown -h $USER {} \;`

This way we avoid changing the ownership on files which are not controlled by homebrew or belong to some other system user.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the /bin directory and type:

chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/bin