# Can't open sqlite3 "This script is just a wrapper for sqlite3"

Tags: sqlite, installation

I had a problem with use of arrow keys in sqlite3 on Mac OS 10.6.
I downloaded sqlite-autoconf-3080403.tar.gz. I did

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Though the new sqlite3 wasn't configured by my machine and I deleted the old sqlite3 in /usr/bin/sqlite3 and moved the new one.

Then when I did

```
sqlite3
```

I got this message:

```
error: '/usr/bin/.libs/sqlite3' does not exist
This script is just a wrapper for sqlite3.
See the libtool documentation for more information
```

Then I tried to upgrade sqlite using brew but maybe it was too late by then because I still get the same error msg.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

BTW I can use sqlite3 when I'm in the decompressed sqlite-autoconf folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question by typing this command into the Terminal:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I found these articles helpful:

[Installed sqlite3 v3.8, but mac terminal still runs old version 3.6 by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89472/installed-sqlite3-v3-8-but-mac-terminal-still-runs-old-version-3-6-by-default)

[Brew doctor says: "Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527521/brew-doctor-says-warning-usr-local-include-isnt-writable)

In my clumsy experience, don't ever do:

```
rm /usr/bin/sqlite3
```

Instead use brew if you are using Mac OS.