# Installing VTK python module on mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: vtk

i am trying to install VTK module 6.2.0 for python on mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1. I tried some reference [[1]](https://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/vetvis/ht10/vtk/instructions_vtk_OSX.pdf),[[2]](http://sankhamukherjee.blogspot.in/2010/03/how-to-install-vtk-with-python-bindings.html) but error comes  "vtk module not found". That means vtk module is not properly getting installed. Can anyone help or suggest any reference working for MAC OSX Yosemite 10.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

installed vtk6.2.0 module using Homebrew [[ref]](http://paulklemm.com/blog/2012/08/20/install-python-together-with-vtk-using-homebrew-for-mountain-lion/). initially got brew link errors but these posts [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527521/brew-doctor-says-warning-usr-local-include-isnt-writable),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable) helped.