# gfortran command not found after installing with 'brew install gcc'

Tags: gcc, homebrew, osx-elcapitan, gfortran

I have Apple's Command Line Tools installed but that doesn't include `gfortran`. I have therefore installed gcc from homebrew (which includes `gfortran`)

```
brew install gcc
```

But then I get this warning

```
Warning: gcc-6.2.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

So I try to link it

```
brew link gcc
```

with this result

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0...
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man7/fsf-funding-6.7
/usr/local/share/man/man7 is not writable.
```

And here I'm stuck. I don't know how to resolve this error. How can I link `gcc`, or even better, why isn't it linked from the beginning?

Comment: This probably happens because of insufficient permissions. Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527521/brew-doctor-says-warning-usr-local-include-isnt-writable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked question I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790578/2161477 which solved my problem.

As mentioned by blackpen in the comments, the problem arises due to insufficient permissions

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```