# How to make Gdal work again with El Capitan?

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, gdal, ogr

I had Gdal installed and it worked fine with MacOS Lion and Yosemite. Now that I moved to ElCapitan, it does not work anymore. 
I realized this while trying to run a command `ogr2ogr` for which I received the error:

```
 bash: ogr2ogr: command not found
```

After looking around, and in particular [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20198/where-do-i-find-the-ogr2ogr-command-for-mac-os-x-lion), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527521/brew-doctor-says-warning-usr-local-include-isnt-writable) I tried  `brew install gdal` , which seemed to have worked after I ran the command

```
  sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/include
```

I also included the following line on my .bash_profile

```
 PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Programs/:$PATH
```

However, when I run the command `which gdal` , I still get nothing in return, and of course I still can't use `ogr2ogr`.

Any suggestions of what I should actually do?