# Building valgrind on OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, valgrind

I was trying to install valgrind on macOS Sierra (version 10.12.6). While running ./configure.sh, this error showed up:

> checking for a supported version of gcc... Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 no (applellvm-8.1.0) configure: error: please use gcc >= 3.0 or clang >= 2.9 or icc >= 13.0

So, I checked my gcc and clang version. The responses are as follows:

> `Ankits-MacBook-Air:valgrind ankitshubham$` gcc --version
>
> Configured
>   with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr
>   --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
>
> `Ankits-MacBook-Air:valgrind ankitshubham$` clang --version
>
> Apple LLVM
>   version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
>   Thread model: posix InstalledDir:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

I don't know how to check if icc>=13.0

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any popular cross-platform package like this it's usually easier to just install with a package manager such as [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Then you just `brew install valgrind` and you're done.

Note also that clang and the Apple developer tools already have similar useful debugging tools, particularly clang's address sanitizer and the malloc debug stuff - this is easily accessible from within Xcode's project settings:

[image]

but you can also use it from the command line if needed.

Comment: True indeed. Actually I was following a web tutorial in which installing valgrind was one of the steps and they did it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Yes, the beauty of using e.g. Homebrew is that someone else has already solved all the configure/build/install issues for you and put them in a script.

Comment: This does not work with High Sierra: "valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
versions newer than Sierra due to an upstream incompatibility.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build."

Answer (score 6):

The issue you are running into has been solved in the current development repo.

If you do want to build valgrind instead of just using a package manager clone the development repo (instructions are below). I am assuming that you are not looking for a specific version of valgrind, the instructions below will build version 3.14 as of the date of this post.

I am making the assumption that you just downloaded the [release](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html) tarball. 
If you instead clone the git repository listed on the [repository page](http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html) it will build just fine on Mac 10.12.6

From the valgrind repository page.

> To clone code from the current repository (anonymous, read-only git
>   access), do this:
>
> git clone git://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git To build the cloned
>   code, follow the instructions in the README file that the clone should
>   give you. Alternatively, the following should work:
>
> ```
>   cd valgrind
>   ./autogen.sh
>   ./configure --prefix=...
>   make
>   make install
> ```

The above steps work fine as of the date on this post running MacOS 10.12.6 with the following version of clang installed.

```
    clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: ...
```

Comment: I've found that the mac I was using did not have the tools called in autogen.sh, for example aclocal. I've found this gist helpful: https://gist.github.com/justinbellamy/2672db1c78f024f2d4fe and I was ready to go.

Comment: I ran in to this problem as well on High Sierra but the above script (from @MartinD's comment) did not help me.  Instead, I installed automake from homebrew (`brew install automake`) but since High Sierra takes away true root priveledges I also had to adjust the install location and link it again, as described in this post (see the April 12 answer by @Pro) [https://stackoverflow.com/a/49805417/2340582]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git &&
cd valgrind &&
./autogen.sh &&
./configure &&
make &&
make install
```