# Check if icc >=13.0

Tags: gcc, icc

This is actually a detour question([Original problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050202/configure-error-please-use-gcc-3-0-or-clang-2-9-or-icc-13-0))I was trying to install valgrind on macOS Sierra (version 10.12.6). While running ./configure.sh, this error showed up:

> checking for a supported version of gcc... Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 no (applellvm-8.1.0) configure: error: please use gcc >= 3.0 or clang >= 2.9 or `icc >= 13.0`

So, how do I check if icc >= 13.0?

Comment: icc is the Intel compiler, do you have it installed? If so just run `icc -v`.

Comment: `icc: command not found` on running `icc -v`

Comment: Interestingly though, I have ColorSync folder in Library folder!