# Node install issues on MacOS 10.14.6

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm very new to Homebrew and Node and am having troubles getting Node up and running.

I successfully installed Homebrew, I then run `brew install node` and get:

```
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: node 13.2.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
```

I run `brew link node` and get:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.2.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Guessing it has something to do with my file not being "writable" but not sure. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have another non-Homebrewed version of Node already installed under `/usr/local`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a permission problem. The directories that homebrew tries to install node into have to be writable. Try this; it sets your user as owner of these subdirectories:

```
chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin
chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/include
```

and then try installing node again. You might have to `brew uninstall node` before `brew install node`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, tried this but got "Operation not permitted"

Comment: try prepending `sudo` in that case; e.g. `sudo chown -R ...`

Answer (score 0):

Grab from the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539521/791609):

`$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` is the solution.